# How to install HBase on Hadoop with 4-node clusters on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have four linux machine one is master machine(192.168.137.157) and other ones are slave machine(192.168.137.148 , 192.168.137.150, 192.168.137.151). I have installed and configured Hadoop 2.7.2 in fully distributed mode successfully. Hadoop output also coming perfectly. I installed and configured HBase-0.98.2-hadoop2 .When I start hbase the output will be like below.

```
 3602 HMaster
 2434 DataNode
 3746 HRegionServer
 3092 NodeManager
 2774 ResourceManager
 2279 NameNode
 3816 Jps
 2620 SecondaryNameNode
 3532 HQuorumPeer
```

But when I run "status" command in hbase shell terminal it shows error like below in hbase log file.

```
hbase(main):001:0> status
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
2016-07-14 02:59:25,667 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:25,770 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:25,975 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:26,281 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:26,785 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:27,789 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:29,807 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:30,012 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:30,115 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:30,324 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:30,629 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:31,137 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:32,152 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:34,172 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:34,478 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:34,583 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:34,789 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:35,094 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:35,601 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:36,615 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:38,634 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:39,143 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:39,249 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:39,453 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:39,758 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:40,265 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:41,281 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:43,292 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:44,303 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:44,409 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:44,615 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:44,920 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:45,427 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:46,441 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:48,449 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:50,469 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:50,576 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:50,779 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:51,083 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:51,590 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:52,602 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:54,609 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:58,637 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:58,741 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:58,945 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:59,250 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 02:59:59,755 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 03:00:00,769 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2016-07-14 03:00:02,784 ERROR [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

ERROR: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

Here is some help for this command:
Show cluster status. Can be 'summary', 'simple', or 'detailed'. The
default is 'summary'. Examples:

  hbase> status
  hbase> status 'simple'
  hbase> status 'summary'
  hbase> status 'detailed'


hbase(main):002:0>
```

sudo nano  /etc/hosts is as below :

```
127.0.0.1        ubuntu
192.168.137.157 (Msater or namenode) 
192.168.137.148  node1 (slave or datanode)
192.168.137.150  node2 (slave or datanode)
192.168.137.151  node3 (slave or datanode)
```

my configuration for  hbase-site.xml in master :

```
configuration>
<property>
     <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.137.157:54310/hbase</value>
 </property> 
 <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
 </property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>hdfs://192.168.137.157:9002/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>192.168.8.157,192.168.137.148,192.168.137.150,192.168.137.151  </value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

my configuration for  hbase-site.xml in slaves :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
         <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
         <value>hdfs://192.168.137.157:54310/hbase</value>
     </property> 
     <property>
            <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
            <value>true</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

and I enabled HBASE_MANAGES_ZK is true in hbase-env.sh for all nodes.
i install zookeeper just in master node

my zoo.cfg configuration

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial 
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between 
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just 
# example sakes.
dataDir=/usr/local/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
#maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the 
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
#autopurge.purgeInterval=1
```

So I can't understand what is the problem ?